# How can I select a number or text in the spinner textfield on entry?

Tags: javafx, spinner

I am using a javafx spinner for Integers. Is there a way to select the value in the Spinner, when I click on it or move to it with TAB? 
Like it works for TextAreas with the following code:

```
myTextArea.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, isFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
        if (isNowFocused) {
            myTextArea.selectAll();
   }
})
```

selectAll() does not work for the spinner. I would like to start typing in the spinner field without previously deleting the initial value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `selectAll()` on the editor (which is a `TextField`) of the `Spinner`.

```
spinner.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isFocused) -> {
    if (isFocused) {
        Platform.runLater(spinner.getEditor()::selectAll);
    }
});
```

When trying this I had to wrap the `selectAll` call inside a `Platform.runLater` call. The `Spinner` itself might be doing something when it gains focus which interferes with the call to `selectAll`; using `Platform.runLater` defers the call to some time after `Spinner` does whatever it does.

Comment: Yes, it works. I tried "spinner.getEditor().selectAll" as well but had no idea about Platform.runLater. I was really desperate, thanks a lot!